# Insert statements with primary key duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, foreign-keys, duplicates

I did some insert statements in MySQL where some entries had the same primary Keys. I got

this output in my MySQL shell:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY' 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY' 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY' 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY' 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '6' for key 'PRIMARY' 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '8' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

So, did MySQL make the entries and just gave me this error or did it stop at this point and didn't make the entries. And how could I solve the problem with primary key errors ? I am aware that these primary keys have duplicates sometimes, but this is for a reason.

Comment: The error is self explanatory meaning u can not have duplicate entry for primary key since its unique. If its auto-incremented then just put NULL for that value in the insert query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries with duplicate primary keys were not created. That is what primary keys are for. If you need to duplicate one, then that field should not be a primary key in the first place.